# HTML 5 gallery drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

Hei,
Iam new to html5 trying to create HTML5 gallery by dragging and dropping from Desktop .

Here is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
 <script>
            function doDrop(event){
                    var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
                    img.src = files[0].getAsDataURL();
                    document.body.appendChild(img);
                }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div style="border:1px solid black; with:100px; height:100px" 
                    ondragover="event.stopPropagnation(); event.preventDefault();"
                    ondrop="event.stopPropagnation(); event.preventDefault(); doDrop(event);"
                ></div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

I want to create the just image gallery not other files like excel, word but my code just works for one picture  . i dont have possbility to drag all pictures at once .Can anyone guide how to do ??

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle multiple files, obviously you need to iterate over that "files" variable, instead of only accessing the first image.

Answer (score 0):

Change the function to iterate loop like below code.

```
              function doDrop(){
                    var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
                  for(var i=0;i<files.length;i++){
                    var img=document.createElement('img');
                    img.src = files[i].getAsDataURL(); // You may also use createObjectURL
                    document.body.appendChild(img);
                   }
                }
```

Look at the demo, Chrome changed the specification to webkitGetAsEntry()

http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/dnd/all_types_of_import.html